# Nodejs request: HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN

Tags: node.js, http, request

I receive `HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN` on a certain page using `request` module. From what I've found on Google, this is caused by an incorrect / malformed server response, however the latter is not under my control. Can I configure request to ignore invalid headers or just give me the whole raw response for processing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-parser-js

So to fix your problem:

1. npm install http-parser-js
2. Add this code before require('request')

   ```
   process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;
   ```

Comment: Yeah thanks, actually I've already found it and it fixed the issue for me)

Comment: Sadly didn't resolve the problem for me - I ended up writing and calling a separate script which cURLed the data I needed. Annoying to have to workaround like this just because Node is being stroppy about headers

Comment: This answer appears to not working anymore. Node v12 introduced a new  `llhttp` parser

Answer (score 26):

Node v12 has a new parser that is more strict with header validation, which can cause the same errors, especially with sites using Imperva/Incapsula that include an invalid header in HTTP 1.1 responses.

A temporary solution is to use the `--http-parser=legacy` option in node's command line, or in the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable.

Since `v12.15.0` and `v10.19.0` you can do this:

```
http.request(url, { insecureHTTPParser: true })
```

Additional information can be found here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27711#issuecomment-584621376

**Edit**: `--http-parser=legacy` is no longer supported in recent versions (including minor versions of v12). A solution for newer node versions is to use `--insecure-http-parser` instead.

Comment: Using `--insecure-http-parser` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, running the code like this worked for me

`nodemon --http-parser=legacy`

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error and provided solutions are not working anymore in node v14 and v16.

I ended up using `node-libcurl` (with node v16.15.1)

```
const { Curl } = require('node-libcurl');

const curl = new Curl();

var api_URL = "https://www.......";

curl.setOpt('URL', api_URL);
curl.setOpt('FOLLOWLOCATION', true);
curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer XYZ']);

curl.on('end', function(statusCode, data, headers) {

    // do something with the data you get..
    // .....

    this.close();

});

curl.on('error', curl.close.bind(curl));
curl.perform();
```

If you like to see how your Header looks like, add this option:

```
   curl.setOpt(Curl.option.VERBOSE, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find what was the problem (which header was causing this) by inspecting headers in the Chrome Dev-Tools in RAW mode.

[image: chrome dev tools screenshot]

Turns out I had "Content-Type:" without a type.