# Streaming a Continous HTTP Response through Node

Tags: node.js, http, npm, stream, request

I am trying to act as a proxy between a client and an IP Camera using a NodeJS server. When I request a real-time stream from the camera, it responds with

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: Application/octet-stream
```

followed by a continuous stream of data. If I open the camera stream in Chrome it initiates a never ending download and curling it also initiates a continuous response.

Node appears to be buffering the response from the camera and parsing it through its HTTP parser each time. This works fine the first time as it has the correct headers but upon the second buffer of data it errors with

```
HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN
```

Can someone please help explain why this is happening? It's a continuous stream of data, why is it trying to parse the HTTP headers on the second buffer? I am not sure whether there is an option I am missing or my camera is not following the HTTP specification properly.

Edit: Example Code

```
const options = {
    family: 4,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Basic ' + base64EncodedAuth,
    },
    host: '192.168.1.131',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/cgi-bin/realmonitor.cgi?action=getStream&channel=1&subtype=0',
    port: 80,
    protocol:'http:',
};


const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
    });
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
    });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});

req.end();
```

The only callback that is hit is the 'error' one.

Comment: Can you show us your node.js code so we can see what you're actually doing.  Questions about code should always contain your code.  I would guess that you want to pipe the response so it just keeps going as long as new data is sent.

Comment: I have added example code. Initially, I was using the request package and piping the response but I got the same error before any response was piped.

Comment: Can't you obtain the data by raw tcp or udp socket? I think you will not have problem with HTTP parsing.

Comment: You say that the only callback that is hit is the error callback.  Then when `error` is hit, what is the error message?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with the stream of data?  Your code doesn't show anything other than a `console.log()`.  I would think what you really want to do is to `.pipe()` it to your client.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva - That's my next plan, I'm just curious as to why I am seeing this behaviour with the HTTP parsing.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The end goal is to proxy the data to the client, the example code just highlights the issue. Piping gives the same issue, I hit the error before any piping occurs. The error code is `HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN` and the error message is `Parse Error`

Comment: Perhaps this: [Nodejs request: HPE_INVALID_HEADER_TOKEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628420/nodejs-request-hpe-invalid-header-token).

Comment: From what I've seen on that particular error, some bugs in nodejs have been fixed in the last year so I'd also ask what version of node.js are you running?

Comment: Mystery solved, I didn't examine the curl log closely enough. The camera is not sending specification complaint responses. I can work around it - I just really wanted to know what was going on. Regardless, thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I further examined the curl log from the camera and noticed that everything was being marked as:

`<= Recv header`

It is never sending the separate CRLF required by the HTTP specification to signal that all the headers have been sent. That is why the parser was trying to parse it as a header and, quite rightly, throwing an error.

Comment: I had a similar problem when requesting to a legacy http server that response cames with no header (just a HTTP 0.9 response). It really throws an HTTP parsing error. And I solved it really using raw sockets...