# hpe_invalid_header_token(bytesParsed: 17) error making request NodeJs to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, express

when I making a request from NodeJs to PHP it will give an error `hpe_invalid_header_token(bytesParsed: 17)`.

My nodejs version is 10.16.0.

```
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url:`${url2}/api/authentication.login.php`,//here url2 is my php application address
            "headers": {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            jar: cookieJar,
            form: {
                password: req.body.password,
                userid: req.body.userid,
                login: req.body.login,
                company_name: req.body.company_name
            }
        };

        request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                res.send(data);
            } else {
                res.send({
                    status: "error",
                    message: "Error Occurred. Please try later",
                    debug: error
                });

            }
        });
    });
```

here I get this error

> debug: {
>        bytesParsed: 17,
>        code: hpe_invalid_header_token
>   }"

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36628420/nodejs-request-hpe-invalid-header-token) could be useful for you.

Comment: I have already tried it but it was giving the same error

Comment: Did you get any fixes?